# Hover button that shows text html/css

Tags: html, css

I'm learning HTML & CSS. Now I am trying to make a hover button that shows some text just like the `tooltip` feature makes. How can I make that happen from here:

```
<title>W3.CSS</title> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=2"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css"> 
<style> 
    /*TEST HERE*/ 
    .w3-button {width:800px;} 
    .w3-button {height:800px;} `
</style>  
<div class="w3-container"> 
    <h2>TITULO AQUI</h2>   
    <p> 
        <button class="w3-button w3-light-blue">Hover in here</button> 
    </p> 
</div> 
/*<div id="button1"></div>*/
```

Comment: you can add a title attribute like `title="Hello world"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `title` attribute is of course the most obvious.

Another attribute based solution is using a custom one and show it with a pseudo, where you could style it some more.

```css
button[data-title] {
  position: relative;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
button[data-title]::after {
  content: attr(data-title);
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%; top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-150%);
  background: gray;
  color: lightgreen;
  padding: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
button[data-title]:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css"> 
<style> 
    /*TEST HERE*/ 
    .w3-button {width:200px;} 
    .w3-button {height:150px;} `
</style>  
<div class="w3-container"> 
    <h2>TITULO AQUI</h2>   
    <p> 
        <button class="w3-button w3-light-blue" data-title="I'm being hovered">Hover in here</button> 
    </p> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Screenshot]

Title is the easiest not very pretty solution...

Other way is to have hidden child tooltip element showing only on hover.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 2px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tooltip {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  width: 150px;
  transition: opacity .5s;
  padding: 1px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  color: #FFF;
}

.hoverTooltip:hover .tooltip {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div title='Here is "native" tooltip'>"native" tooltip via title</div>
<br /><br />
<div class="hoverTooltip">
  hover element tooltip
  <span class="tooltip">Here is your custom styled tooltip</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just use the title attribute

```
<button class="w3-button w3-light-blue" title="this is a title">Hover in here</button>
```